# Optional function argument which subsets a list?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, function, loops

Let's suppose that I have the following `DataFrame` to work with:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "CST": [1, 2, 3],
        "BRAND": ["A", "B", "C"],
    }
)

print(df1)

   CST BRAND
0    1     A
1    2     B
2    3     C
```

Next, I define the following helper function:

```
def add_col(df, field_name, only_x=True):
    attrs = ["X", "Y", "Z"]
    for attr in attrs:
        df["_".join([field_name, attr])] = 999
    return df

df2 = add_col(df1, "BRAND")
print(df2)

   CST BRAND  BRAND_X  BRAND_Y  BRAND_Z
0    1     A      999      999      999
1    2     B      999      999      999
2    3     C      999      999      999
```

As you can see in the function above, I have a boolean argument `only_x` which is not implemented/used anywherefor the moment inside the function. The goal of this argument is self explanatory: when set to `True` (default), in the above example, it should only create the `BRAND_X` column.

This might be a fairly easy implementation but, having little experience in Python/programming, I struggle with finding the best approach. The only one that I could come up with is the following:

```
def add_col(df, field_name, only_x=True):
    attrs = ["X", "Y", "Z"]
    if only_x:
        attrs = [attrs[0]]
    for attr in attrs:
        df["_".join([field_name, attr])] = 999
    return df

df2 = add_col(df1, "BRAND", only_x=True)
print(df2)

   CST BRAND  BRAND_X
0    1     A      999
1    2     B      999
2    3     C      999
```

Although this does work, I'm not sure this is the best way to go. Is this considered good code in the way the logic is structured? If not, what would be some better approaches here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test the parameter when assigning the variable

```
def add_col(df, field_name, only_x=True):
    attrs = ["X"] if only_x else ["X", "Y", "Z"]
    // rest of function
```

But a more general design might be to make `attrs` a parameter with a suitable default.

```
def add_col(df, field_name, attrs = ["X", "Y", "Z"]):
```

Then when you want only the `X` column, use `attrs=["X"]` in the call.

Comment: Its not ideal to have a mutable list as a default argument to a function see https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/gotchas/ -> The pattern in your first answer is much better IMO. Either that or use `def add_col(df, field_name, attrs =None):  ... if not attrs: attrs = ['X', 'Y', 'Z']`

Comment: That's only an issue if you mutate the parameter, it's not a problem for read-only parameters.

Comment: Correct, but its just bad practice, it can easily lead to bugs if you aren't careful

Comment: Yes, but not in this case, and I'm not going to complicate the code because it looks similar to something else that can have problems.